# How do Germans call null

Tags: null

In german null means 0, so how do they call null (like null reference) ?

Comment: they use the English pronunciation of "null" :)

Comment: In C null is a void pointer to 0.

Answer (score 2):

or you could use the german equivalent of "nothing" which is "nichts".

As for NullReference we use the "same" as in english: Nullreferenz.